# How to limit the connections number Finagle creates?

Tags: scala, tcp, finagle, twitter-finagle

I use Finalge `https://twitter.github.io/finagle/` to test the timeout case like this:

1. Server side: in the RPC definition, Just sleep 10 secs and return.
2. Client side: call RPC function using `within` like `within(50.milliseconds) onSuccess { ... } onFailure { ... }`
3. Many clients: use about 100 clients to call the RPC function at the same time

The result is that all the RPCs are timeout of course. But, when I use `netstat` to check the connection I find that there are 100 `ESTABLISHED` connection. The question is can I limit the connections number Finagle create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
hostConnectionLimit(10)
```

in your ClientBuilder to limit the connections to each host. "Host" here refers to the server side boxes.

Source code [here](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/builder/ClientBuilder.scala#L542).